# Xidel keeps adding XMLNS in the output

Tags: linux, bash, xidel

I am trying to extract html code from a div:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<div id="tbParams">
    <table class="ParametrList" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
        <tr class="Parametr altrow">
            <td class="Nazev">
            Hello                </td>
            <td class="Hodnota" style="vertical-align: top;">

            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

...with xidel:

```
xidel input.html -e '//div[@id="tbParams"]' --output-format html
```

For some reason it keeps adding XMLNS attributes to the output:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="tbParams">
    <table class="ParametrList" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
        <tbody xmlns=""><tr xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="Parametr altrow">
            <td class="Nazev">
            Hello                </td>
            <td class="Hodnota" style="vertical-align: top;">

            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

If I remove `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` from the `<html>` tag, then it is OK.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated the question, please check again.

Comment: You need to use the option `--ignore-namespaces`

Comment: It's working. But why I can't find this in the manual?